# AWS Lambda with Zappa fails on "Unable to import module 'handler': No module named builtins"

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've deployed my application to AWS Lambda with Zappa. The deployment went fine without any issues. But when I try to reach the app via AWS API Gateway I get a 500 response.

The logs says

> Unable to import module 'handler': No module named builtins

The environment runs on Python 2.7. I've added `future` to the Pipfile but it still won't work.

When I check the code in Lambda I can see the following code

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import base64
import boto3
import collections
import datetime
import importlib
import inspect
import json
import logging
import os
import sys
import traceback
import zipfile

from builtins import str
```

I can't find what can be wrong. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Can you post a picture of your solution (i.e. folder structure)? You must not be packaging the builtins library with your lambda function.

Comment: You probably wrongly set the name of the Lambda handler on the AWS console.

Comment: It is handler.lambda_handler, which is default for Zappa. Why do think that's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I'm using pipenv to install my packages, but for some reason the packages wasn't installed inside the virtual environment, which made Zappa to not include them to AWS Lambda. I had to install them manually in PyCharm by going through `Settings > Project > Project Interpreter` and add the packages there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updagred python2.7 to python3.6 and facing the same issue, Please do let me what would be the fix as I am not using PyCharm. using terminal only.

Comment: Have you re-installed all the packages inside your `pipenv`?

Comment: I removed my previous environment which was created by `vitualenv env -p python2.7` and than I created new one with `virtualenv env -p python3.6` after the I just did `pip install -r requirement.txt`